# Error: Request failed: 401 - Unauthorized API Request React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use an API in my front-end project. I am using `React/Typescript`.
It has been mentioned in the document for the `api` that the authorization uses a key with the name of `token` which has a `value` as well and it has been said to use the authorization as header.

I am using a `.env` file for the value of the token.

this is my my code now:

```js
// defining baseUrl and apiKey
const API_BASE_URL = "somevalue";
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
const apiToken = `Bearer ${apiKey}`;
interface RequestOptions {
  method: string;
  body?: FormData | null;
}

// makeRequest function to handle the common logic for making API requests.
async function makeRequest(
  url: string,
  options: RequestOptions = { method: "GET" }
) {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: apiToken, 
    'key': 'token',// Pass the token in the 'Authorization' header
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    
  };
  console.log('Headers:', headers);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: options.method,
      headers,
      body: options.body,
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(
        `Request failed: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`
      );
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`);
  }
}
export async function getPosts(
  page: number,
  perPage: number,
  sortBy: string,
  sortDirection: string,
  searchPhrase: string,
  categoryId: number
) {
  const url = new URL(`${API_BASE_URL}/posts`);
  url.searchParams.append("page", page.toString());
  url.searchParams.append("perPage", perPage.toString());
  url.searchParams.append("sortBy", sortBy);
  url.searchParams.append("sortDirection", sortDirection);
  url.searchParams.append("searchPhrase", searchPhrase);
  url.searchParams.append("categoryId", categoryId.toString());

  return makeRequest(url.toString());
}

export async function createPost(
  title: string,
  content: string,
  category_id: number,
  image: File
) {
  const url = `${API_BASE_URL}/posts`;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("title", title);
  formData.append("content", content);
  formData.append("category_id", category_id.toString());
  formData.append("image", image);

  return makeRequest(url, { method: "POST", body: formData });
}

export async function getCategories() {
  const url = new URL(`${API_BASE_URL}/categories`);
  return makeRequest(url.toString());
}
```

And this is what I get when I am trying to use the function in another page of the website:

`Error: An error occurred: Request failed: 401 - Unauthorized`

Comment: Custom variable must start with `REACT_APP_`

Comment: @YuvarajM still the same error

Answer (score 1):

> You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_

Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

It is not a good practice to use secret key in `.env` because it will be exposed in your JS as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`

Comment: I changed the name of the variable to `REACT_APP_API_KEY`, but I am still getting the same error. 
And I actually had that question in mind. I was using .env for back-end, and I knew it wouldn't be the best idea to use it in front-end. What would be a better way to use the key in this situation?

Comment: Would it be a better practice if I make a back-end for it and try to make secure requests to that?

Comment: If your are also developing the back-end, You have to use `cookies` for best case or on authenticating the user store the encrypted key in `session` or `localStorage`

Comment: Are you sure changed the name in both .env and js?

Comment: Well actually, this whole thing is for a technical interview. the api documentation has been given to me. I thought it would be time-consuming to do the back-end myself, but I can try.

Comment: yes. I changed the name of the variable in my `.env` file to:

`REACT_APP_API_KEY= thekeyvalue `
and this is my `apiKey` on the apiService:
`const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;`

Comment: try this `set "REACT_APP_API_KEY=KEY" && npm start` if you are using windows

Comment: Still the same. Some how, the line `console.log('Headers:', headers);` is now showing that the token is set to: `"Bearer #key" `, but it is still giving the 401 - unauthorized

Comment: I don't know why? one thing if you are using backend and frontend in same folder just separate them and place the .env file in root folder

Comment: Yeah It is confusing me as well :d 
.env file is in the root directory. I'm gonna try re-doing the back-end to see what happens. thanks a lot for the time man!

Comment: Atleast accept my answer @Sadraw :)

Comment: Or one upvote please